# Required attributes for input not working on form submit

Tags: html

I wrote this simple form that should require the users to input their phone number if the submit button is hit. Instead, nothing happens. Can someone please help me?
Here is the code for my form:

```
<form id="subscribeForm" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="payment margin-top-30">
        <div class="payment-tab payment-tab-active">
            <div class="payment-tab-trigger">
                <input checked id="{PAYMENT_TYPES.folder}"
                    class="payment_method_id" name="payment_method_id"
                    type="radio"
                    value="{PAYMENT_TYPES.id}" data-name="m-pesa2">
                <label for="{PAYMENT_TYPES.folder}">{PAYMENT_TYPES.title}</label>
                <img class="payment-logo {PAYMENT_TYPES.folder}"
                  src="{SITE_URL}includes/payments/{PAYMENT_TYPES.folder}/logo/logo.png"
                  alt="{PAYMENT_TYPES.title}">
            </div>
            <div class="payment-tab-content">
                <p>
                    A Push notification shall be sent to the Phone
                    Number to complete payment.
                </p>
                <div class="payment-tab-content">
                    <div class="row payment-form-row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="card-label form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                    name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="button big ripple-effect
            margin-top-40 margin-bottom-65 subscribeNow" 
            id="subscribeNow">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Add the form `name` too (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `novalidate="novalidate"` from `<form>`